# How to solve a real time transaction problem in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I encounter two problems regarding the transaction which needs to be solved in JavaScript.

Let's say some transaction requests are going to happen after (2seconds, 5seconds, 6seconds, 9seconds, 12seconds, 16seconds...). 
I need to write a simple function that makes sure there is at least a 5sec interval between two requests and ignores others. So in this example, only transactions at 2seconds, 9seconds, and 16seconds are accepted. 
Another problem I had is that writing a function that only accepts a request at 0s, 5s, 10s, 15s...whatever is closer to the 5s mark and ignore others. This time, the function should accept transactions at 2sec, 5sec, 9sec, and 16sec and ignore others.

`

```
setTimeout(transaction(2), 2000);
setTimeout(transaction(5), 5000);
setTimeout(transaction(6), 6000);
setTimeout(transaction(9), 9000);
setTimeout(transaction(12), 12000);
setTimeout(transaction(16), 16000);
//first problem: print 2,9,16 
//second problem: print 2,5,9,16
```

`

I have an idea to solve these two problems using setTimeout/setInterval/Closure but I'm not sure about how I can integrate them together.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this client-side or server-side JavaScript?

Comment: Also - something like this is best solved using RxJS rather than JS's built-in timeout primitives.

Answer (score 0):

Use RxJS's `debounceTime`:

> https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html
>
> Discard emitted values that take less than the specified time between output

```
let transactions$ = getObservableForTransactions();
transactions$
    .pipe(
        debounceTime( 5000 )
    )
    .subscribe( txn => console.log( txn ) );
```

### Demonstration

For your use-case specifically, I don't know where your "transactions" are coming from - but here's a more fleshed-out example using `debounceTime`:

```
// Step 1: Input:
let input = [
    { value:  2, delay:  2000 },
    { value:  5, delay:  5000 },
    { value:  6, delay:  6000 },
    { value:  9, delay:  9000 },
    { value: 12, delay: 12000 },
    { value: 16, delay: 16000 }
];

// Step 2: Set-up an Observable Subject:
let obs$ = new Subject<number>();

// Set-up an initial anonymous subscriber to print all values (without debouncing):
obs$.subscribe( {
    next: v => console.log( 'value emitted: %o', v );
} );

// Step 3: Set-up the debounced subscriber:
obs$.pipe( debounceTime( 5000 ) )
    .subscribe( { next: v => console.log( 'Debounced value emitted: %o', v ); } );

// Step 4: Spam `setTimeout` to trigger the process:
for( var item in input ) {
    setTimeout( () => obs$.next( item.value, item.delay );
} 

// Step 5: Open your browser console and view the results in real-time.
```

Comment: This is server-side. I want to make sure the requests from the client do not process so often. Is it possible to write a function in vanilla javascript?

Comment: @Phil Without knowing exactly how your pipeline is set-up and what `transaction(n)`  does (is it a function that returns a function? is it a function called directly? are there any `async` considerations?) I can't give an answer using only vanilla-JS.

Comment: Assume all `transaction(n)` does is printing out the number `n` in a 5s interval and ignores other transaction calls in between. What I'm thinking is using closure to create a private counter as a condition for setInterval function.

Comment: @Phil Your description in your comment-reply implies `function transaction` calls `setInterval` itself, but the code you posted in your question shows the `setInterval` call happening **outside** `function transaction`.